# How do I allow the user to guess the letter and corresponding number, hangman style?

Tags: python

I have a working program that:

Takes a phrase and encodes it with randomized numbers from 1-26
Allows user to get 3 letters, of their choice, and their computer assigned number
But what I would like to do is allow the user to be able to guess a letter and what they think the correct letter is, if their guess is correct allow them to carry on but if it's wrong, to say so and let them try again.Eventually allowing them to guess the whole phrase as well.

Hopefully that makes sense :)

Here's the Code:

```
import string, random
import pandas as pd
#User Input
title = input("Please Enter A Title For This Puzzle: ")
if len(title) == 0:
    print("String is empty")
    quit()

phrase = input("Please Enter A Phrase To Be Encoded: ")
if len(phrase) == 0:
    print("String is empty")
    quit()


if not  phrase.islower():
    print("Please use lowercase for the phrase")
    quit()

#Numbers get assigned to the letters
nums = random.sample(range(1, 27), 26)
code = dict(zip(nums, string.ascii_lowercase))

print(    )
#Giveaway letters
num1 = int(input("Enter the first giveaway letter you would like (Note:a=0, b=1 ect): "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second giveaway letter you would like (Note:a=0, b=1 ect): "))
#Code for Grid
code2 = {'Number': [[nums[num1]],[nums[num2]]],
        'Letter': (string.ascii_lowercase[num1],string.ascii_lowercase[num2]),
        }
#'Start' of Puzzle for the user  
print (  )
print ("The Title Of This Puzzle Is", title)
print(    )

df = pd.DataFrame(code2, columns = ['Number', 'Letter'])
code = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, nums))
code.update({" ":100})
encoded = [code[item] for item in phrase]



print (df)
print(    )
print ("Hint: 100 is always a space")
print (encoded)
```

Note: I have asked this question before however the link provided wasn't that helpful, in this particular situation. An example or slight snippet of code would be appreciated.

I have been trying on my own but it looks like a mess and wouldn't work with this program. Regardless here it is:

```
def make_a_guess():

          print("A is " + str(a))
          print("Make a guess...")
          Article_Guess = input("What letter: ").lower()
          Numerical_Guess = int(input("What number: "))

          if Article_Guess == 'a' and Numerical_Guess == a:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, A: " + str(a))

          elif Article_Guess == 'b' and Numerical_Guess == b:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, B: " + str(b))

          elif Article_Guess == 'C' and Numerical_Guess == c:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, C: " + str(c))

          elif Article_Guess == 'D' and Numerical_Guess == d:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, D: " + str(d))

          elif Article_Guess == 'E' and Numerical_Guess == e:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, E: " + str(e))

          elif Article_Guess == 'F' and Numerical_Guess == f:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, F: " + str(f))

          elif Article_Guess == 'G' and Numerical_Guess == g:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, G: " + str(g))

          elif Article_Guess == 'H' and Numerical_Guess == h:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, H: " + str(h))

          elif Article_Guess == 'I' and Numerical_Guess == i:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, I: " + str(i))

          elif Article_Guess == 'J' and Numerical_Guess == j:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, J: " + str(j))

          elif Article_Guess == 'K' and Numerical_Guess == k:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, K: " + str(k))

          elif Article_Guess == 'L' and Numerical_Guess == l:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, L: " + str(l))

          elif Article_Guess == 'M' and Numerical_Guess == m:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, M: " + str(m))

          elif Article_Guess == 'N' and Numerical_Guess == n:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, N: " + str(n))

          elif Article_Guess == 'O' and Numerical_Guess == o:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, O: " + str(o))

          elif Article_Guess == 'P' and Numerical_Guess == p:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, P: " + str(p))

          elif Article_Guess == 'Q' and Numerical_Guess == q:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, Q: " + str(q))

          elif Article_Guess == 'R' and Numerical_Guess == r:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, R: " + str(r))

          elif Article_Guess == 'S' and Numerical_Guess == s:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, S: " + str(s))

          elif Article_Guess == 'T' and Numerical_Guess == t:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, T: " + str(t))

          elif Article_Guess == 'U' and Numerical_Guess == u:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, U: " + str(u))

          elif Article_Guess == 'V' and Numerical_Guess == v:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, V: " + str(v))

          elif Article_Guess == 'W' and Numerical_Guess == w:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, W: " + str(w))

          elif Article_Guess == 'X' and Numerical_Guess == x:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, X: " + str(x))

          elif Article_Guess == 'Y' and Numerical_Guess == y:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, Y: " + str(y))

          elif Article_Guess == 'Z' and Numerical_Guess == z:
               print_letters()
               print("Correct, Z: " + str(z))
```

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're trying to achieve. That the user can specify a position and guess which letter is at that position? In that case, I would use a list and replace all your `elif`s with one check `yourlist[index] == letter`

Comment: @lucidbrot, unfortunately i haven't used that format before so i don't understand what you mean, could you perhaps show and example or explain it it me with just one letter, for example 'A'. Thank you

Comment: I might answer you later today, when I have the time to test my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used pandas dataframes before. I'm sure you could also use those, but I find it easier to use the builtin structures.
What I recommended in the comments was using a list of characters. That could look like this:

```py
mylist = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
print(mylist[1])
# outputs 'b', because that's at position 1 in the list
```

However, since you already have a dict of the numbers and characters in your code, we can just as well use that `code` dict:

```py
import string, random

def make_a_guess(solution):
    print("Make a guess...")
    letter = input("What letter: ").lower()
    number = int(input("What number: "))

    # the -1 is a default value to be returned if no valid number was provided. None would work just as well, if not better.
    if solution.get(number, -1) == letter:
        print("Correct, {} = {}".format(letter, number))
    else:
        print("Wrong, {} != {}".format(letter, number))

#User Input
title = input("Please Enter A Title For This Puzzle: ")
if len(title) == 0:
    print("String is empty")
    quit()

phrase = input("Please Enter A Phrase To Be Encoded: ")
if len(phrase) == 0:
    print("String is empty")
    quit()


if not  phrase.islower():
    print("Please use lowercase for the phrase")
    quit()

#Numbers get assigned to the letters
nums = random.sample(range(1, 27), 26)
code = dict(zip(nums, string.ascii_lowercase))

print('')

while True:
    make_a_guess(code)
```

Of course, you'll still have to add a stopping condition and a way to allow the user to enter the correct phrase as numbers. But the `make_a_guess` function should be what I think you were looking for.

---

#### Bonus Question

As you asked in a comment if I have an idea why the numbers from my code are off by one compared to the pandas indexing.
That is likely simply due to this line here, which samples from a minimum of `1` instead of `0` up to but exclusive `27`.

```py
nums = random.sample(range(1, 27), 26)
```

If you change that to the following, it will also start at 0.

```py
nums = random.sample(range(0, 26), 26)
```

Normally, arrays count from `0`, not from `1`, and it seems pandas keeps to this convention.

Comment: wow this works really well in all the situations I have used it in, so thank you. However I am quite confused as to why you have put a -1 within the if statement.

Comment: Ah, I should have clarified that. But when I realized, I thought you'll likely manage googling that yourself. I have just now looked at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to realize that `None` would have been smarter. What my code does: It returns the number only if the specified letter is there. If it is not there, it will return `-1` - a number that never matches because you only have positive numbers.

Comment: @Dumknight please have a look at my edit at the bottom. It's just a guess, perhaps I misunderstood your follow-up question